# Mongoose embedded document requirement check/validation does not bubble up

Tags: mongoose

I have a simple use-case where I want to cancel saving in case an embedded document has a missing required field.

Here's a simple example with some pseudo-code:

```
var Post = new Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    tags: [Tag]
})

var Tag = new Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true }
});
```

When I save a Post with no title, I do get the error. When I save a post with a title and a tag, but the tag has no title, i do not get any errors, which i think I should according to Mongoose Documentation: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/embedded-documents.html

The following model won't produce any errors:

```
{"title": "new post", "tags": [ {"author":"me"} ]
```

I would expect that it did.

Comment: `a post with a title and a tag, but it has no title` Can you edit this part please? Is `Post.title` empty or not?

Comment: Post.title is NOT empty, but Tag.title is, this is a pseudo-code example, the tag is supposed to have a title as well. When I try to save this model, it should give me an error, but it doesn't. I edited the original question.

Comment: Can you try defining the `Tag` schema before the `Post` schema? Idea from: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/722

Comment: Yes, that's it! Funny I thought it would not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `Tag` schema must be defined before `Post` schema.

Idea from: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/722

Also we can see that `Comments` schema is declared before `BlogPost` schema here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/embedded-documents.html